# How to edit cell in listcontrol mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc, edit, listcontrol

I need edit my text in second column and I don't want use MFC grid control.
how I can edit cell by kicking on it.
please give me simple example.

There what I have:

```
void CTab1::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_LISTC);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTab1, CDialogEx)
    ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_LIST1, OnEndEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTab1 message handlers
BOOL CTab1::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    m_LISTC.InsertColumn(0, L"Buttons", LVCFMT_LEFT,50);
    m_LISTC.InsertColumn(1, L"Time", LVCFMT_LEFT, 50);
    m_LISTC.InsertColumn(2, L"State", LVCFMT_LEFT, 40);

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        CString F;
        F.Format(L"F%d", i + 1);
        m_LISTC.InsertItem(m_LISTC.GetItemCount(), F, -1);
        int row = 1;
        int col = 10;
        m_LISTC.SetItemState(row, col, m_LISTC.GetItemState(row, col) | LVN_ENDLABELEDIT);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void CTab1::OnEndEdit(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* pLVDI = reinterpret_cast< NMLVDISPINFO* >(pNMHDR);
    if (pLVDI->item.pszText)
        m_LISTC.SetItemText(1, 0, pLVDI->item.pszText);
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

but it not working. so I still can edit cell's of second column.

Comment: This question is offtopic. If you are asking for code you need to demonstrate and show minimal understanding of the problem domain. What have you tried? Why did you not succeed? What specific programming issues are you having problems with?

Comment: ok I will edit my question

Comment: `LVS_EDITLABELS` is a [List-View Window Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx). You have to set it when creating the listview. The notification message you are looking for is [`LVN_ENDLABELEDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774814.aspx).

Comment: True. fixed. but not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to utilize LVS_EDITLABELS and LVN_ENDLABELEDIT for editing other columns than the first.

I just must create edit control on that cell...