# Edit cell in list control by clicking in MFC -- RESOLVED

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

**Problem Dsecription: Application to show an editable table in new window. e.g.: In the following table, I want to be able to edit the register values. I tried to write the application using MFC on Visual Studio 2015 in C++**

[image]

===========================================================================
I'm working on a MFC application using Visual Studio 2015 in C++

I've created a Dialog Editor In which I want to show a list of registers (type list control) with two columns, one that specifies the registers numbers and a second column to show their values. I've started with the simplest case, and created such list with only one register successfully with the following code:

`.cpp` file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication4.h"
#include "MFCApplication4Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


CMFCApplication4Dlg::CMFCApplication4Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_MFCAPPLICATION4_DIALOG, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication4Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, listCtrl);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication4Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST1, &CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnLvnItemchangedList1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


BOOL CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("Register Number"));
    listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("Register Value"));
    listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(0, 200);
    listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(1, 400);

    int nItem = listCtrl.InsertItem(0, L"0x00");
    listCtrl.SetItemText(nItem, 1, L"01000001");

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

void CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

HCURSOR CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnLvnItemchangedList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

`.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "afxwin.h"

class CMFCApplication4Dlg : public CDialogEx
{

public:
    CMFCApplication4Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor


#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFCAPPLICATION4_DIALOG };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnLvnItemchangedList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
    CListCtrl listCtrl;
};
```

I would like to be able to edit the value of the register by clicking on it once or twice and typing the new value. I tried adding the following function to the header beneath the last line of CListCtrl listCtrl:

`afx_msg void RightButtonClick(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, CPoint point);`

the implementation of the function in `.cpp` file:

```
afx_msg void CMFCApplication4Dlg::RightButtonClick(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, CPoint point)
{
    //listCtrl.SetFocus();
    //CEdit* itemToEdit = listCtrl.EditLabel(1);

    // The string replacing the text in the edit control.
    LPCTSTR lpszmyString = _T("custom label!");

    // If possible, replace the text in the label edit control.
    CEdit* pEdit = listCtrl.GetEditControl();

    if (pEdit != NULL)
    {
        pEdit->SetWindowText(lpszmyString);
    }
}
```

and I added the following message to the message map in the `.cpp` file (last line in the block BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP):

`ON_WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_LIST1, &CMFCApplication4Dlg::RightButtonClick)`

but unfortunately that's what I'm getting no results.

I've tried reading some more, and I've spent few hours trying to fix it, but haven't succeeded. I've tried to follow the answers to similar posts which are listed below:

[Make single items editable in a list control (C++, MFC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669924/make-single-items-editable-in-a-list-control-c-mfc)

and

[How to edit cell in listcontrol mfc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169344/how-to-edit-cell-in-listcontrol-mfc)

but I wasn't able to implement the suggestions that were written there, I didn't understand how to connect all the parts of the answers. Additionally, I tried using this guide:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_messages_events.htm

Unfortunately, nothing helped. I have a feeling that I'm missing something fundamental, perhaps I'm not handling the messages as I should. I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain to me what I'm missing and how to fix it.

Please let me know if my question isn't clear enough or if there's any other problem with it, so I'll edit it and get better.

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: Did you create your list control using the [LVS_EDITLABELS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles) style? Besides, that message map entry is pretty much bananas. It's wildly unclear, what you hope that to accomplish.

Comment: See [Control Notification Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn006-message-maps#control-notification-messages).

Comment: Do not add the solution to the question, please post an answer yourself and mark it.

Comment: See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I used this [guide](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/making-a-mfc-list-control-editable/) which solved my problem